# Mongo Aggregation Get Difference between values of array objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Good day, I am having difficulty using aggregation in mongodb to get the date difference between two values in an array, my document structure looks as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c591420a890362dec70fcf4"), 
    "tracetag" : "T00005", 
    "amounts" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c5915bea890362dec71015a"), 
            "startdate" : ISODate("2019-02-15T04:49:02.000+0000"), 
            "enddate" : ISODate("2019-02-15T04:50:05.000+0000"), 
            "amount" : 18.975946800811833, 
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c5915bea890362dec71015b"), 
            "startdate" : ISODate("2019-02-16T04:49:02.000+0000"), 
            "enddate" : ISODate("2019-02-16T04:51:52.000+0000"), 
            "amount" : 3.5755730555836203, 
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c5915bea890362dec71015c"), 
            "startdate" : ISODate("2019-02-17T04:49:02.000+0000"), 
            "enddate" : ISODate("2019-02-17T04:50:04.000+0000"), 
            "amount" : 2.3937573313380383, 
        }
    ], 
}
```

the number of "amounts" entries are not fixed, so it could be 1 or 50 etc.

for each document, I would like to get the difference between the 'enddate' and 'startdate' (aka the duration) and I would like to sum the duration (lets call this totalduration). I can do the total 'amount' without issues, but getting the duration gives me error ""cant $subtract aarray from a array", my aggregation looks like this:

```
{ 
            "$project" : {
                "tracetag" : 1.0,  
                "totalamount" : {
                    "$sum" : "$amounts.amount"
                }, 
                "totalduration" : {
                "$sum" : {
                     "$subtract" : [
                        "$amounts.enddate", 
                        "$amounts.startdate"
                    ]
                  }
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so I managed to answer my own question: the 'amounts' need to be split using the $unwind operator, then a field can be added to each record (duration), in my case I wanted the duration in minutes. Afterwards I grouped everything again

```
{
      "$unwind" : { "path" : "$amounts" }
    },
    {
      "$addFields" : {
          "duration" : { "$divide" : [ { "$subtract" : [ 
"$enddate", "$startdate" ]}, 60000.0 ] }
      }
    },
```